# How to get the click outside window event

Tags: c#, wpf, window, mouseclick-event

I make a very simple window:

```
var wndPpList = new Window()
{
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
    ShowInTaskbar = false,
    BorderBrush = GetColour_Cyan(),
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),
};
```

now I want to make that when I click outside it, it closes.

I have seen a lot of posts where in order to achieve this, they activate the mouse

```
wndPpList.CaptureMouse();
wndPpList.Deactivated += (sender, args) => 
{
    wndPpList.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    wndPpList.Close();
};
```

but the event Deactivated is just not fired.

Thanks for any help

Patrick

Comment: You can try to capture Application.Deactivated event instead.

Comment: I can't because it is in a static method. Additionally if I have not misunderstood the meaning of this function I would not work because I am clicking outside the secondary window into the primary (the application).

Comment: It is not static.

Comment: My method is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the MouseDown event you can check if the event was raised outside of the popup. Then you can close the popup window.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var wndPpList = new Window()
            {
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                BorderBrush =  Brushes.Cyan,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),
            };
            wndPpList.Show();

            // Handle the mouse down event of the application window
            Application.Current.MainWindow.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!wndPpList.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    wndPpList.Close();
                }
            };
        }
```

if you need to fire the event more then one time you need to register and unregister it properly. This is an example with a button to open the popup. However if you open two popup windows at the same time you will get propblems. So you should disable the button while the popup is shown or use some other machanism to only show one popup.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MouseButtonEventHandler windowMouseDownHandler;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterMouseDownEvent();
            var wndPpList = new Window()
            {
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Cyan,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),
            };
            wndPpList.Show();

            windowMouseDownHandler = (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!wndPpList.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    wndPpList.Close();
                }
            };
            // Register the event handler function
            Application.Current.MainWindow.MouseDown += windowMouseDownHandler;
        }

        private void UnregisterMouseDownEvent()
        {
           
            if (windowMouseDownHandler != null)
            {
                Application.Current.MainWindow.MouseDown -= windowMouseDownHandler;
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: Sorry again. The problem was related with the fact that I was using wndPpList.ShowDialog(); instead than wndPpList.Show(); so the secondary window was blocking everything

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: I was just thinking about that problem. Thanks twice!

Comment: What about un-registering upon the event after the wndPpList.Close(); ?

Comment: yeah that would be a better option. I was to quick responding :)